# Eclipse: C-code in C++ static lib, referenced by C++ lib results in undefined reference

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, undefined-reference, gcc4.4

I've read almost all the "undefined reference" topics here, have spent 2 days in trying different linkage options, but with no results. I'm desperate!

I'm on Linux Red Hat platform with Eclipse 3.6.1 and GCC 4.4.7.

I'm porting a large project from Solaris studio (where it works) to Eclipse.
I have C++ Static Library project (e.g. Common_Lib) which includes transformations.c + .h files - pure C code.

The transformations.h file is wrapped with

```
#ifndef TRANSFORMATIONS_H_
#define TRANSFORMATIONS_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo(int *x);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

/* transformations.c */
#include "transformations.h"

void foo(int *x)
{
   /* calculations on x*/
}
```

I have another C++ static lib project (e.g. Factory_Lib) with method Do_Transform() which calls to foo() from transformations.h. This project is built properly.

```
#ifndef FACTORY_H
#define FACTORY_H
#include "transformations.h"

class CFactory
{
   public:
   void Do_Transform(int *x);
};

// factory.cpp
#include "factory.h"

void CFactory::Do_Transform(int *x)
{
   foo(x);
}
```

And the last one - executable - C++ project (e.g. Worker), which calls to Factory_Lib's Do_Transform(), which calls to foo().

```
#include factory.h

int main
{
   CFactory fact = new CFactory();
   int x=0;

   fact.Do_Transform(&x);

   return 0;
}
```

Worker refuses to be built (linked), "*undefined reference to foo()*" appears.

If the call to foo() is done **directly** from main() of Worker, the problem **doesn't** appear!

In Worker project I've tried to reference the Common_Lib in *Reference projects*, in *Settings->Linker* references, as additional libraries *-l* in the linker **without** the *Referenced projects*, etc. I've tried many combinations, but without success.

What must I do to make it work?!?!? I've run out of ideas.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have #endif in transformations.h file at the very end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get a luck by the following:  `-lFactory -lCommon` , the order is important.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem! But I don't understand why. Can you please explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have the code of both Common_Lib and  Factory_Lib , why dont you compile both using the common c++ compiler itself. I mean compile both libs as a C++ library (no code change needed other than remove extern "C" from transformation.h )

I dont understand why you need extern here? There is no C compiler involved here. Both the libs are C++.

Comment: Common_Lib, which is C++ project, contains pure-C files: transformations.c . The file is compiled with gcc instead of g++. The code in it is C only, and must remain C only.

Comment: have you linked against both the archives while making worker. Other wise i dont see a issue.